# maximum number of characters for select option

Tags: html, selection

In `input type text` we can increase maximum number of characters using `maxlength="50"` i tried using it in `select` and in `option` but it did not work how do you increase the maximum number number of characters in the option in the `input type select`?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `select` isn't an `input` type; it's an autonomous element. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: @OzgurBar i have an entry in option that is a bit long it is from database when i display it in option select it is a bit short, user will not understand it if the word is cut off

Comment: Normally your field has the complete length. If you set a with you crop it.

Comment: not exactly a solution but you can specify the entire text in option's `title` attribute if it's cropped in `select`. the problem here is not the maxlength, the text is too long to fit in `select` control, right?

Comment: @OzgurBar yes that is the problem it wont fit in the option because it is too long what do mean by specifying in option's title?

Comment: try this `<option value="1" title="Very long text to fit in select control">Cropped Text</option>` if you have a list, it will display a tooltip when you hover on option. but will not work if it's already selected.

Comment: i see i can write the data from database as title and as value then as option then the user can see it as title is that what you mean?meaning it is not a solution but a work around it might work if there is no other choice lol thanks for idea @OzgurBar

Comment: no problem. but you can always display the selected option in a separate control using `javascript` in case it doesn't fit `select` control.

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum set, so there is no need increase the maximum.

Your real problem seems to be that you want to truncate the text of an `option` element. You should try to *reformulate* a long piece of text rather than truncate it.